# Parse JSON Data Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, json, parsing, xamarin

hi I'm new to android programming.I'm doing coding for a mobile app.I called the products which were in JSON using array.now I want to click on specific product and then want to get that specific product details from another JSON API.But that product details are not in array format.So I can't call the URL like I did before.It goes to break mode in visual.
This is how I called before:

```
            //Code to Parse and process Data
            JObject theRe= JObject.Parse(bResults);
            JArray bResults= (JArray)theRe["ShowAllProducts"];
```

How can I call to one product object which the JSON is not in Array format.

Comment: Show your JSON, please.

Comment: Are you developing android with .NET & Xamarin? (Because you used the Xamarin tag)

Comment: ya I'm using xamarin

Comment: You could use Newtonsoft.JSON then to parse your JSON, then you do not have to deal with JObjects in C# and you will have a solution working on all platforms.
To help you fix your issue you really need to post a JSON example/structure otherwise everyone has to search for the needle in the hay.

Comment: Please show your JSON and tell us what do you want to get from your json file.

Comment: Have you try to use specific class to parse your json?
You can try http://json2csharp.com

Comment: @GaneshCauda thanx a lot for helping I already fixed it.I had to parse data using dynamic method.